# Heroku The term 'heroku' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: heroku

I added Heroku to Windows, I downloaded Heroku-cli to my laptop, and when I wanted to upload a NodeJs project from Visual studio on Heroku this problem happened, how do I solve it ?

I add this statement in visual studio :

```
  heroku login
```

I get this Error :

```
 heroku : The term 'heroku' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
 operable program. Check 
 the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
 again.
 At line:1 char:1
 + heroku login
 + ~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (heroku:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/855 Try this

Comment: Thank you , my Problem was solved @Tin Nguyen